# How can I use JavaScript in Katalon Studio?

Tags: javascript, automation, katalon-studio

Sometimes, I encounter an element which I'm unable to click with a normal Selenium script so I have to use javascript to execute my script.

How can I use JavaScript in Katalon Studio?

Comment: What? Please clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
((JavascriptExecutor) DriverFactory.webDriver).executeScript('Your JavaScript-Code', argument);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a custom keyword, inside of the package "yourPackage":

```
@Keyword
static clickJS (TestObject to, int timeout) {
    WebUI.waitForElementVisible(to, timeout)
    try {
        WebUI.click(to)
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
        WebElement element = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(to, timeout)
        JavascriptExecutor executor = ((driver) as JavascriptExecutor)
        executor.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', element)
    }
    throw(e)
}
```

Then, you can call the function inside your test script with:

```
CustomKeyords.'yourPackage.yourClass.clickJS'(findTestObject("yourObject"))
```