# Katalon Studio pick the Date Error

Tags: katalon-studio

I am trying to do a Script with Katalon Studio to test a Webpage. However on the first Page i have to put in Destination and Dates. It worked perfectly with the Destination however I cant figure out a way to pick a date so he can press Search so I get to the next page. I tried to click it with xpatch or id. No change. I allways get the same Error:

Test Cases/MyHotelo FAILED because (of) Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/Page_myhotelo/Datum' (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (224, 476). Other element would receive the click: ...

Someone has an idear how to fix it?

The website is myhotelo.com

[myhotelo.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgmaO.jpg)

Comment: Please share relavant HTML and your script.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote here: [How can I write javascript on Katalon tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768223/how-can-i-write-javascript-on-katalon-tool/50466641#50466641):

You can try using a custom keyword, inside of the package "yourPackage":

```
@Keyword
static clickJS (TestObject to, int timeout) {
    WebUI.waitForElementVisible(to, timeout)
try {
    WebUI.click(to)
}
catch (Exception e) {
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement element = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(to, timeout)
    JavascriptExecutor executor = ((driver) as JavascriptExecutor)
    executor.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', element)
}
throw(e)
}
```

Then, you can call the function inside your test script with:

```
CustomKeyords.'yourPackage.yourClass.clickJS'(findTestObject("yourObject"))
```

This 'unable to click... other element would receive the click' is a common issue, you can read about it here: https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/6100/object-visible-but-not-clickable.